# Can't escape single quotes in shell

Tags: command-line, escape-characters

I'm trying to make a command to do a perl substitution on a batch of php files in a directory. The string I want to replace has single quotes in it, and I can't get it to properly escape the in shell.

I tried echoing the string with unescaped quotes, to see what perl would be getting:

```
echo 's/require_once\('include\.constants\.php'\);/require_once\('include\.constants\.php'\);require_once\("\./functions/include\.session\.inc\.php"\);/g'
```

and it doesn't have the single-quotes in the result:

```
s/require_once\(include.constants.php\);/require_once\(include.constants.php\);require_once\("\./functions/include\.session\.inc\.php"\);/g
```

However, when I try to escape the single quotes:

```
echo 's/require_once\(\'include\.constants\.php\'\);/require_once\(\'include\.constants\.php\'\);require_once\("\./functions/include\.session\.inc\.php"\);/g'
```

I get the prompt to complete the command:

```
>
```

What I want it to parse to is this:

```
s/require_once\('include.constants.php'\);/require_once\('include.constants.php'\);require_once\("\./functions/include\.session\.inc\.php"\);/g
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"` instead of `'` on the outside, then you only have to escape two `"` inside the expression.

```
echo "s/require_once\('include.constants.php'\);/require_once\('include.constants.php'\);require_once\(\"\./functions/include\.session\.inc\.php\"\);/g"
```

Comment: I get command completion prompt from this :(

Comment: @user13743 - did you copy paste my solution. what type of shell do you have?

Comment: Yeah, I copied and pasted your solution. `$ echo $SHELL` gives `/bin/bash`

Comment: @user13743 - Try just `echo "s/require_once\('include"` if that works add some more of the string `echo "s/require_once\('include.constants.php'\);/"`. Repeat until it breaks. This should narrow down the error.

Answer (score 1):

No expansion or evaluation of any kind takes place inside a single-quoted string, not even backslash escapes. As Nifle and canen posted, use double-quotes instead, and escape those instead of the single quotes. However, you only need to escape them for your shell's benefit. If you plan to use this `s///` directly inside a perl script, no escaping is necessary because you normally wouldn't enclose `s///` in quotes to begin with.

Additionally, your `s///` operation will fail because you have your delimiter character `/` in your replacement string. Either backslash-escape the slashes in `/functions/include`:

```
s/require_once\('include.constants.php'\);/require_once\('include.constants.php'\);require_once\("\.\/functions\/include\.session\.inc\.php"\);/g
```

or choose a different delimiter:

```
s@require_once\('include.constants.php'\);@require_once\('include.constants.php'\);require_once\("\./functions/include\.session\.inc\.php"\);@g
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use double quotes?

```
"s/require_once\('include.constants.php'\);/require_once\('include.constants.php'\);require_once\("\./functions/include\.session\.inc\.php"\);/g"
```

Comment: this does not print the " in the second require_once

Answer (score 0):

You escape single quotes with a single quotes. For example, let's say you wanted to make a git commit with the following message: Updated BaseActiveRecord's save() method.

To do this, run the following command (and note that I escape the single quote with a single quote).

```
git commit -m 'Updated BaseActiveRecord''s save() method.'
```

You could also accomplish your goal using double quotes (and not escaping the single):

```
git commit -m "Updated BaseActiveRecord's save() method."
```

However, do note that double quotes on the command line cause certain things to get expanded (i.e. $vars). Hope this helps.